How do I test and benchmark different Linux schedulers?
I am currently trying to test if borrowed virtual time performs as they claimed on their bvt paper: rcs.uwaterloo.ca/papers/bvt.pdf I have my environment set up and i used the patch created for 3.5.0 by Forks · patch-3.5.0-bvt1 (github.com) . Now, I am stuck. I just need several benchmarks to compare the bvt patch against the linux's regular cfs.
